# Product ini file name not being set to the launcher name

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, tycho

I'm creating an Eclipse RCP product and I set the launcher name to be "MyProduct." Maven/ Tycho build seem to be successful. But only the launcher name changes and not the ini; it keeps eclipse.ini.

```
<launcher name="MyProduct">
   <solaris/>
   <win useIco="true">
      <ico path="/com.myComp.myProd/icons/prod.ico"/>
      <bmp/>
   </win>
</launcher>
```

I thought the ini file was supposed to change to the launcher name if it's set. I've used the Eclipse product editor as well as an xml editor to make the changes. But nothing seems to work. Does something else need to be changed?

Directory Screen Capture:

[image: Directory Screen Capture]